# Change only one column of one row in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let's say I have a SQLite database of 1000 rows with 10 columns named `col1, col2, ..., col9, id`.

How to change only the `col7` of a specific row? Here is more or less what I want to achieve:

```
WITH mytable CHANGE col7 = 'newvalue' WHERE id = '156'
```

Is it possible to do it in 1 query? i.e. without having to read the whole row first, and repost the whole row, etc.

Comment: `UPDATE myTable SET col7 = 'newvalue' WHERE id = 156` . . .

Comment: Please tell me `id` is not actually a string (char/varchar/nvarchar/etc) data type. Or is quoting integer values some sort of SQLite oddity?

Comment: @MichaelL. `id` is an auto-increment timestamp string, but stored as a little-endian UTF16 boolean.

Comment: @Basj `... stored as a little-endian UTF16 boolean` SQLite has no datatype of type `boolean`. And you should explain us how can you store a **string** as a **boolean**. In whichever environment - that statement makes really no sense, to me.

Comment: @BobMalooga Sorry that my string-timestamp-autoincrementing-boolean joke didn't work ;)

Comment: Oh, well. It wasn't so obvious that it was a joke. It's a while I'm on this site and I see so many absurdities being asserted or asked, every now and then. And they are mostly serious... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax you're looking for is an [`update`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) statement:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    col7 = 'newvalue'
WHERE  id = '156'
```

Answer (score 2):

As Siyual said (and should make an answer), it's very straightforward:

```
UPDATE myTable SET col7 = 'newvalue' WHERE id = 156
```

[Here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) is documentation on SQLite's version of the `UPDATE` statement.